# How to Project forward a decreasing trend in R from a csv

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I'm trying to do trend analysis on Carbon Output to estimate when we will reach Carbon neutrality based on current trends with some sort of confidence interval. Any Idea how i could do this using R and then hopefully show my results in a graph.

I've tried building a linear regression model using a different software I'm more familiar with (minitab) but hoping I can do the same in R to keep all my code for this project in the one language, and I'm also not sure if a linear regression is even appropriate, as the data isn't necessarily linear

Once I'm on my home PC if the question is still not answered I can show the data I currently have if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for your data and more specificy requirements, you can do a line plot with a trend line in `tidyverse` and `ggplot`. The `geom_smooth()` function adds a linear model via `lm`, you can turn on `se` to TRUE for confidence intervals.

```
library(tidyverse)

carbon <- read_csv("https://datahub.io/core/co2-fossil-global/r/global.csv")

carbon %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Total)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Global CO2 Emissions from Fossil Fuels since 1751",
       subtitle = "Source: https://datahub.io/core/co2-fossil-global") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Do you plan to include anything additional in your regression model?

**Update**

This is authors data.

```
carbon <- data.frame(fossil_fuel =c(69.50426, 68.33529, 68.08371, 68.65155, 72.15907, 71.78847, 72.04432, 73.28336, 73.99019, 73.55609, 74.91764, 77.81596, 78.85325, 73.80238, 75.30230, 70.61190, 70.01013, 67.43910, 64.03521, 57.17204, 55.26921, 52.13594, 49.62602, 47.03623),
          year <- seq(from = 1996, to = 2019, by = 1))

carbon %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=fossil_fuel)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Fossil Fuel %") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
lm(fossil_fuel ~ year, data=carbon)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         year  
    1693.89        -0.81
```

Comment: So my data is fossil fuels as a percentage of current energy market makeup so is as follows: 
69.50426, 68.33529, 68.08371, 68.65155, 72.15907, 71.78847, 72.04432, 73.28336, 73.99019, 73.55609, 74.91764, 77.81596, 78.85325, 73.80238, 75.30230, 70.61190, 70.01013, 67.43910, 64.03521, 57.17204, 55.26921, 52.13594, 49.62602, 47.03623
From 1996 to 2019

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. How can i extend the x-axis so I can see where it intercepts.

Comment: What do you mean by extending the x-axis? It is in years, do you like to go back to year 0? I don't know if this is any help. If you are interested in that intercept, you could calculate it in R as well.

Comment: I've extended the x-axis forward to find the year in which the line intercepts the graph (2034) using the data from 2008 onwards- since thats the year it begins to decrease. This has worked perfectly, Thanks.

Comment: Ah okay, I got you wrong. But intercept I usually understand the intersection with y-axis. You were looking for intersection with x-axis to see when 0% is achieved. Still, I think you can calculate those intersections instead of extending the plot and try to figure it out visually.